# Multivariate polynomial regression with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, regression

I have many samples `(y_i, (a_i, b_i, c_i))` where `y` is presumed to vary as a polynomial in `a,b,c`  up to a certain degree. For example for a given set of data and degree 2 I might produce the model

`y = a^2 + 2ab - 3cb + c^2 +.5ac`

This can be done using least squares and is a slight extension of numpy's polyfit routine. Is there a standard implementation somewhere in the Python ecosystem?

Comment: I've posted code here to solve this problem [https://github.com/mrocklin/multipolyfit](https://github.com/mrocklin/multipolyfit)

Answer (score 20):

sklearn provides a simple way to do this.

Building off an example posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463226/how-to-do-gaussian-polynomial-regression-with-scikit-learn):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn import linear_model

#X is the independent variable (bivariate in this case)
X = np.array([[0.44, 0.68], [0.99, 0.23]])

#vector is the dependent data
vector = np.array([109.85, 155.72])

#predict is an independent variable for which we'd like to predict the value
predict= np.array([[0.49, 0.18]])

#generate a model of polynomial features
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)

#transform the x data for proper fitting (for single variable type it returns,[1,x,x**2])
X_ = poly.fit_transform(X)

#transform the prediction to fit the model type
predict_ = poly.fit_transform(predict)

#here we can remove polynomial orders we don't want
#for instance I'm removing the `x` component
X_ = np.delete(X_,(1),axis=1)
predict_ = np.delete(predict_,(1),axis=1)

#generate the regression object
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
#preform the actual regression
clf.fit(X_, vector)

print("X_ = ",X_)
print("predict_ = ",predict_)
print("Prediction = ",clf.predict(predict_))
```

And heres the output:

```
>>> X_ =  [[ 0.44    0.68    0.1936  0.2992  0.4624]
>>>  [ 0.99    0.23    0.9801  0.2277  0.0529]]
>>> predict_ =  [[ 0.49    0.18    0.2401  0.0882  0.0324]]
>>> Prediction =  [ 126.84247142]
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to include the implementation of the `delete` function? Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, it's numpy, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

Comment: what does `PolynomialFeatures ` do explicitly? can I see the code?

Comment: this doesn't make sense to me, why does `fit_transform ` return both the polynomial feature matrix (vandermonde matrix) AND also the predictions? :/

Comment: how does this compare to just doing it manually like `c_pinv = np.dot(np.linalg.pinv( Kern_train ),Y_train)`?

Comment: `predict` variable should be a 2d array `[[0.49, 0.18]]`

Answer (score 2):

polyfit does work, but there are better least square minimizers out there. I would recommend kmpfit, available at

http://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn-beta/kmpfittutorial.html

It is more robust that polyfit, and there is an example on their page which shows how to do a simple linear fit that should provide the basics of doing a 2nd order polynomial fit.

```
def model(p, v, x, w):       
   a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k = p      #coefficients to the polynomials      
   return  a*v**2 + b*x**2 + c*w**2 + d*v*x + e*v*w + f*x*w + g*v + h*x + i*y + k  

def residuals(p, data):        # Function needed by fit routine
   v, x, w, z = data            # The values for v, x, w and the measured hypersurface z
   a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k = p   #coefficients to the polynomials  
   return (z-model(p,v,x,w))   # Returns an array of residuals. 
                               #This should (z-model(p,v,x,w))/err if 
                               # there are error bars on the measured z values


#initial guess at parameters. Avoid using 0.0 as initial guess
par0 = [1.0, 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0] 

#create a fitting object. data should be in the form 
#that the functions above are looking for, i.e. a Nx4 
#list of lists/tuples like (v,x,w,z) 
fitobj = kmpfit.Fitter(residuals=residuals, data=data)

# call the fitter 
fitobj.fit(params0=par0)
```

The success of these things is closely dependent on the starting values for the fit, so chose carefully if possible. With so many free parameters it could be a challenge to get a solution.

Comment: Can you post an example of multivariate regression using polyfit? I'm not convinced that this is supported. After looking through the documentation for kmpfit I fear this might be true of this library as well.

Comment: What are you trying to fit, y(x) = a*x**2 + b*x + c? Anyway, you can certainly do multivariable fitting with mpfit/kmpfit.

Comment: No, y(v, x, w) = a*v**2 + b*x**2 + c*w**2 + d*v*x + e*v*w + f*x*w + g*v + h*x + i*y + k

Comment: So this library would work but it solves the problem through an iterative method. Least squares polynomial fitting can be done in one step by solving a linear system. I've posted code in another answer that does this using numpy.

Answer (score 2):

sklearn has a nice example using their Pipeline [here](http://scikit-learn.org/0.17/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_underfitting_overfitting.html). Here's the core of their example:

```
polynomial_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degrees[i],
                                         include_bias=False)
linear_regression = LinearRegression()
pipeline = Pipeline([("polynomial_features", polynomial_features),
                     ("linear_regression", linear_regression)])
pipeline.fit(X[:, np.newaxis], y)
```

You don't need to transform your data yourself -- just pass it into the Pipeline.

Comment: That example does not use multivariate regression.