# How to do gaussian/polynomial regression with scikit-learn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Does scikit-learn provide facility to perform regression using a gaussian or polynomial kernel? I looked at the APIs and I don't see any.
Has anyone built a package on top of scikit-learn that does this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either you use Support Vector Regression `sklearn.svm.SVR` and set the appropritate `kernel` (see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/svm.html#regression)).

Or you install the latest master version of sklearn and use the recently added `sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures` (see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L399)) and then OLS or `Ridge` on top of that.

Answer (score 24):

**Theory**

Polynomial regression is a special case of linear regression. With the main idea of how do you select your features. Looking at the multivariate regression with 2 variables: `x1` and `x2`. Linear regression will look like this: `y = a1 * x1 + a2 * x2.`

Now you want to have a polynomial regression (let's make 2 degree polynomial). We will create a few additional features: `x1*x2`, `x1^2` and `x2^2`. So we will get your 'linear regression':

```
y = a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + a3 * x1*x2 + a4 * x1^2 + a5 * x2^2
```

This nicely shows an important concept [curse of dimensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality), because the number of new features grows much faster than linearly with the growth of degree of polynomial. You can take a look [about this concept here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoQa2Svvo2U).

**Practice with scikit-learn**

You do not need to do all this in scikit. [Polynomial regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#polynomial-regression-extending-linear-models-with-basis-functions) is already available there (in **0.15** version. Check [how to update it here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22914458/1090562)).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn import linear_model

X = [[0.44, 0.68], [0.99, 0.23]]
vector = [109.85, 155.72]
predict= [0.49, 0.18]

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_ = poly.fit_transform(X)
predict_ = poly.fit_transform(predict)

clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_, vector)
print clf.predict(predict_)
```

Comment: sklearn's Pipeline makes this even easier: http://scikit-learn.org/0.17/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_underfitting_overfitting.html

Comment: @Salvador Dali. Sorry, what is "vector" exactly?

Comment: @GianlucaJohnMassimiani, vector = y_training and predict = X_test.

Comment: I am trying to get the code for `PolynomialFeatures` for `d>2`, do you have it?