# Not able to import PolynomialFeatures, make_pipeline in Scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm not able to import the following modules in an ipython notebook:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
```

### The following error pops up

> ImportError: cannot import name PolynomialFeatures

The same error also appears for `make_pipeline`.

I'm a newbie in **scikit-learn**, please help out.

I'm using the **miniconda** installation of python and the version number for **scikit-learn** is **0.14.1**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polynomial Features is included for next version of scikit-learn and is not available in 0.14.1. Please update to 0.15-git if you want to use it. The same holds for make pipeline.

To get the bleeding edge version:

```
git clone git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git

python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Please read: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/index.html#git-repo

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your current version of scikit:

```
import sklearn
print sklearn.__version__
```

if it is less than **0.15.0**, then you have to upgrade it. In addition to an excellent answer of Abhishek, you can follow [official installation process](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) (which is described for various OS).

If you are using pyCharm, it can be done even simpler: File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter and then select your package and click upgrade[image]

(I selected another one, be cause my scikitlearn is the newest)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was following IBM course on machine learning, and was using this line:

```
from sklearn import PolynomialFeatures
```

and it should be:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
```

Hope it can help others.