# Prediction techniques using scikit-kearn (Polynomial regression)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I try to test a first example using `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn import linear_model

X = [[0.44, 0.68], [0.99, 0.23]]
vector = [109.85, 155.72]
predict= [0.49, 0.18]

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_ = poly.fit_transform(X)
predict_ = poly.fit_transform(predict)

clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_, vector)
print clf.predict(predict_)
```

But i have these errors:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/__init__.py:148:
 RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary
 incompatibility
  from ._shortest_path import shortest_path, floyd_warshall, dijkstra,\
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_validation.py:5:
  RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary
  incompatibility
  File "hi.py", line 1, in <module>
  from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
  ImportError: cannot import name PolynomialFeatures
   python -V --> 2.7.6
```

Please, how can I deal with these errors?
Bests.

Comment: The version of your scikit learn seems to be old. You can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914458/not-able-to-import-polynomialfeatures-make-pipeline-in-scikit-learn

Answer (score 1):

You can check your `sklearn` version, use:

```
import sklearn
print('Version {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))
```

For me it shows:

```
Version 0.17.1.
```

Then check (from help of `PolynomialFeatures`) which version offers `PolynomialFeatures` and make an update. If your version is 0.14.1 or below, you will get this error. Check this page for more details on how to upgrade it: [Not able to import PolynomialFeatures, make_pipeline in Scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914458/not-able-to-import-polynomialfeatures-make-pipeline-in-scikit-learn) (Official: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html)

Comment: root@graphene-119:~# sudo python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 23 2017, 15:49:48)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sklearn
>>> print('Version {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sklearn' is not defined
>>>

Comment: Ok, it seems you don't even have `sklearn` installed, hence the error `ImportError: No module named sklearn`. Just visit the **scikit-learn** website and read more on how to install it.

Comment: Both `sklearn` and `tensorflow` are different libraries. Installing one doesn't install the other by default. You will need to install both. By the way, I am still confused why you wrote in the first sentence of your question "using tensorflow:". You are not using `tensorflow` in your code at all. It's just all `sklearn`.

Comment: is there a polynomial regression with tensorflow ?

Comment: A simple Google search for keywords **polynomial regression with tensorflow** will give you answers to your questions. The answer to your question is "yes" btw.