# Linear Regression with quadratic terms

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I've been looking into machine learning recently and now making my first steps with scikit and linear regression.

Here is my first sample

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np

X = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]]
y = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]

clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit (X, y)

print(clf.predict([11]))
==> 22
```

The output is as expected `22` (apparently scikit comes up with `2x` as the hypothesis function). But when I create a slightly more complicated example with `y = [1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100]` my code just creates crazy output. I assumed linear regression would come up with a quadratic function (x^2) but instead I don't know what is going on. The output for 11 is now: `99`. So I guess my code tries to find some kind of linear function to map all the examples.

In the tutorial on linear regression that I did there were examples of polynomial terms, so I assumed scikits implementation would come up with a correct solution. Am I wrong? If so, how do I teach scikit to consider quadratic, cubic, etc... functions?

Comment: Take a look at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_polynomial_interpolation.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463226/how-to-do-gaussian-polynomial-regression-with-scikit-learn#27015806

Comment: @lejlot, you have to read more carefully. The very first sentence is: `This example demonstrates how to approximate a function with a polynomial of degree n_degree by using ridge regression.` This chapter is not about classical interpolation, but indeed about linear regression.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`LinearRegression` fits a linear model to data. In the case of one-dimensional `X` values like you have above, the results is a straight line (i.e. `y = a + b*x`). In the case of two-dimensional values, the result is a plane (i.e. `z = a + b*x + c*y`). So you can't expect a linear regression model to perfectly fit a quadratic curve: it simply doesn't have enough model complexity to do that.

That said, you *can* cleverly transform your input data in order to fit a quadratic curve with a linear regression model. Consider the 2D case above:

```
z = a + b*x + c*y
```

Now let's make the substitution `y = x^2`. That is, we add a second dimension to our data which contains the quadratic term. Now we have another linear model:

```
z = a + b*x + c*x^2
```

The result is a model that is quadratic in `x`, but still linear in the coefficients! That is, we can solve it easily via a linear regression: this is an example of a basis function expansion of the input data. Here it is in code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x = np.arange(10)[:, None]
y = np.ravel(x) ** 2

p = np.array([1, 2])
model = LinearRegression().fit(x ** p, y)
model.predict(11 ** p)
# [121]
```

This is a bit awkward, though, because the model requires 2D input to `predict()`, so you have to transform the input manually. If you want this transformation to happen automatically, you can use e.g.[`PolynomialFeatures`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) in a pipeline:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(2), LinearRegression())
model.fit(x, y).predict(11)
# [121]
```

This is one of the beautiful things about linear models: using basis function expansion like this, they can be very flexible, while remaining very fast! You could think about adding columns with cubic, quartic, or other terms, and it's still a linear regression. Or for periodic models, you might think about adding columns of sines, cosines, etc. In the extreme limit of this, the so-called "kernel trick" allows you to effectively add an *infinite* number of new columns to your data, and end up with a model that is very powerful – but still linear and thus still relatively fast! For an example of this type of estimator, take a look at scikit-learn's [`KernelRidge`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/kernel_ridge.html).

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot.

Comment: I got a value error for the line 'model.predict(11 ** p)', "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:". I used this line instead: model.predict([[11]] ** p)