# Polyfit for more than one variable?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Does it exists a function similar to *polyfit* to interpolate n variables? *polyfit* use x, y, N, where N is the degree, instead I would like to use x, y, z, and N. Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multivariate polynomial regression with numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988082/multivariate-polynomial-regression-with-numpy)

Comment: @AmiTavory - Not an exact duplicate.  That uses `numpy` where this question is asking in MATLAB.

Comment: @rayryeng Sorry, missed that. Thanks. Retracted.

Comment: @AmiTavory - No problem at all.  Just wanted to point it out.  However, there are some concepts in that post that are applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't a direct function which you can use in MATLAB. However, you can solve the problem manually using [`fitlm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitlm.html).