# multiple polynomial regression with different degrees for the different parameters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I have velocity data (mf) for a fluid at 5 axial locations (x) for 14 different combinations of two parameters of the fluid (Re, k). The velocity data is dependent on Re, k and x.

I would like to use sklearn to do polynomial regression of my data as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988082/multivariate-polynomial-regression-with-numpy), but I am facing some problems:

1. How should I build the X matrix (the matrix of the independent variables)? It seems to me that there are 3 independent variables here (Re, k  and x) but I have 14 values of Re, 14 values of k and only 5 values for x.
2. Would it be possible to regress with degree=1 w.r.t. Re and k and degree=3 w.r.t. x?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have three 2d array-like objects `Re`, `k`, and `x`, you can create polynomial features of degree=3 on just `x`, by applying the `PolynomialFeatures` transformer to just `x` before stacking the features into a single matrix.

```
poly_x = PolynomialFeatures(3)
X = np.hstack([Re, k, poly_x.fit_transform(x)])
```