# Multidimensional polynomial function fitting with errors for fitting parameters

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scikit-learn

The scipy function `scipy.optimize import curve_fit` can fit 1D functions and returns `popt` (Optimal values for the parameters) and `pcov` (the estimated covariance of popt).

There are also packages to fit multidimensional functions like sklearn ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31467522/4391129)). However there is no estimated covariance for the parameters.

Is there any way to get the parameters and the corresponding errors with python?

Example code:

```
x = ...
y = ...

def f(x, a, b, c, d, e):
    return a*x[0] + b*x[1] + c*x[2] + d*x[3] + e*x[4]

fit = fit(f, x, y)
```

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/)?

Comment: @DavidG  I don't understand how they do the multidimensional fitting. They say: "The fitting routines accept data arrays that are one dimensional and double precision. So you need to convert the data and model to be one dimensional. A simple way to do this is to use numpy.ndarray.flatten" For me that sounds as if multidimensional fitting is not possible with lmfit

Comment: It might not be. I'm no expert using lmfit but just thought I should post it incase it was useful, seems like it isn't.

Comment: yes thank you for your post. The topic "How can I fit multi-dimensional data?" obviously is missleading